# Trying to train a network outputs: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for max_pooling2d

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Trying to train a convolutional neural network on a sample dataset with shape (256, 256, 3) gives me a ValueError.

I've checked the shape of my data (it's already in channels last, like tensorflow wants it). I've tried using the same code as other people but it doesn't work. I've gone through my dataset to see if the format of the data was correct, and I didn't seem to find any errors.

The code for my CNN is the following:

```
X = pickle.load(open("X.pickle", "rb")) # Shape (256, 256, 3)
y = pickle.load(open("y.pickle", "rb")) # The labels

X = X / 255.0 # Normalizing the data

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1)
```

I expected the network to run smoothly, but it outputed the following (not gonna post the whole error log because it's too long):

```
File "neuralnet.py", line 18, in <module>
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 2 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d_1/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,64,128,1].
```

**Edit**
Posting my keras.json file:

```
{
    "epsilon": 1e-07, 
    "floatx": "float32", 
    "image_data_format": "channels_last", 
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

It previously was on data_format channels_first and backend theano. I've changed that, but I have to say that I'm using the tensorflow implementation of Keras directly.

Changing to channels_last and backend tensorflow has changed the output of the console, now it gives this error on the model.fit line:

````
ValueError: You are passing a target array of shape (8118, 1) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. `categorical_crossentropy` expects targets to be binary matrices (1s and 0s) of shape (samples, classes). If your targets are integer classes, you can convert them to the expected format via:
```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_binary = to_categorical(y_int)
```

Alternatively, you can use the loss function `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead, which does expect integer targets.
````

Comment: Were you using the Theano backend before? What are the contents of your ~/.keras/keras.json ?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I think I used theano before, but this is in a new environment. Is there a keras.json file for tensorflow? Where can I find it?

Comment: In ~/.keras/keras.json , same as I indicated before

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I've updated my post with what you said. I tried changing it to what it should be but it still gives errors (now they're different).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your last problem, you have this solution.

First, change the loss function to `"binary_crossentropy"` instead of `"categorical_crossentropy"`. (since you have two classes I assume, with the sigmoid activation), provided that your data is one-hot encoded.

If you do not want to one-hot-encode your data (this is to transform 0 and 1 into [1,0] and [0,1]), you may use "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", just like the error suggests.